# Change font color on scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change the background and font color by class switching:

HTML

```
    <body>
    <div class="back">
            <h1>TEST<br>TEST</h1> 
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">TEST TEST TEST</div>
    </body>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    var scroll_pos = 0;
    $(document).scroll(function() { 
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(scroll_pos > 500) {
            $("body").addClass("changeColor");
            $("back h1").addClass("changeColortext");
        } 
        else {
            $("body").removeClass("changeColor");
            $("back h1").removeClass("changeColortext");
        } 
    });
});
```

*changeColour* and *changeColortext* are styles with just different colour and background values like this:

CSS

```
 .changeColortext {
color: #B63E3E;
}
```

While it works perfectly for changing the background, the font color never changes. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: can you show us the html code. how you are applying the classes in html?

Comment: I've added the HTML

Comment: i've tried your code and it will work when using `$(".back h1)`.. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0n39rd71/)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post your HTML markup? I suspect without looking at it that you meant to do

`$(".back h1").removeClass("changeColortext");`

Notice the period before back, which denotes you are looking for a class. Would need to use # if it is an ID.

Comment: I've added the HTML. I've tried it with period before back, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for help. It works now. In my CSS I had text attributes in .back h1 class, but when I've moved them to .back it works perfectly.